# Migrating server to new host

Tags: vmware

I have been trying to migrate a server to a new host, and have come across a solution that seems like it should work [(LINK)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8drFEj1k9zc&t=90s)

My problem is that the downloading/ probably uploading of the files is taking way too long (about a month, server size is 1TB provisioned with 450 GB used)

I was trying to use a USB drive connected directly with the server so that I could copy it over faster, but there's a whole other rabbit hole to go down with that, which seems to have ended in a poorly documented dead end.

Any help with how to do this easier/a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can shut the VM down, you could try exporting the VM as an OVF (it *should* skip downloading any of the unused space on the 1TB VMDK) or you could also attempt to SCP the VM between systems.

Also, if you have licensing to support both vMotion and Storage vMotion, PowerCLI's `Move-VM` cmdlet would work excellently in this scenario.